# Yunohost and Freedombox

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

Has anyone tried installing Yunohost or Freedombox on top of the Raspbian Strech lite image?

I am installing freedombox on top of Raspbian using the `freedombox-setup` package available in raspbian package repositories.

Yunohost is also a great alternative.

Have anyone tried installing them both on the same RPi?
Will there configurations mess up each other?

Comment: I am currently considering Yunohost for my new install on two RasPi 4B devices during 2022. However, from [my experience](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133799/does-anyone-have-experience-with-running-yunohost-on-a-raspi), you're not likely to get any support for it here, even if it's installed on a raspi. If you're still around, see you on the [Yunohost forums](https://forum.yunohost.org/). 