# Does anyone have experience with running Yunohost on a RasPi?

Tags: server, nextcloud

I see [this unanswered question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78928/yunohost-and-freedombox?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C70.4290) from Feb 2018, and no other results from [a search for "Yunohost"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Yunohost) in this stack. Does anyone here use their raspi device for selfhosting using Yunohost? I am currently considering Yunohost for my project in 2022, and would like to know if others here have experience with it. It looks like a great solution as a replacement for the whole Docker/Portainer deployment scheme, with Yunohost being more of a complete distro which can be flashed to an SD-card as an OS, then configured further from there. From what I have learned of it so far, there [may be issues with the selfhosted email stack](https://forum.yunohost.org/t/is-yunohost-a-good-solution-for-my-usecase-see-mindmap/18057/5), which is enabled by default as an integral part of the system, but which can be bypassed with various hacks. Many of the apps which I intend to install as part of my selfhosted home server project, such as Bitwarden and NextCloud, can be installed easily from the Yunohost interface.

I'm just really looking to see if there are current Yunohost users here, should I decide to go down this path, who could answer questions as they arise. I'm also on the [Yunohost forums](https://forum.yunohost.org/u/frittro/), where there seems to be lots of [posts tagged with `raspberrypi`](https://forum.yunohost.org/tag/raspberrypi).

Comment: polling questions are off topic here ... please ask a question about a specific problem

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I guess that's my answer then. I'll toodle off back to the Yunohost forums then, and ask my questions there as they arise. Thanks for that. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that there are [no other](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Yunohost) questions or answers here which mention Yunohost specifically, and given @jsotola's comment, I am left to asume that the answer to my question is a firm "no", there aren't any Yunohost users here. That's a pity, given the number of [posts tagged with raspberrypi](https://forum.yunohost.org/tag/raspberrypi) on the [Yunohost forums](https://forum.yunohost.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I have been successfully hosting Yunohost on an RPI 4B for a few weeks now.

I am using the 4gb RAM option.

Apps I am successfully using:

- [Send](https://github.com/YunoHost-Apps/send_ynh/blob/master/README.md)
- [Private Bin](https://github.com/YunoHost-apps/privatebin_ynh/blob/master/README.md)
- [Pleroma](https://github.com/YunoHost-Apps/pleroma_ynh/blob/master/README.md) (Bit Tricky this one.)
- a Blog using [Bludit](https://github.com/YunoHost-Apps/bludit_ynh/blob/master/README.md) as a CMS
- [Standard Notes](https://github.com/YunoHost-Apps/snserver_ynh/blob/master/README.md) Sync Server (Also a bit Tricky)

So far I have had zero issues running these apps once I got them installed. I do wonder how many more I could successfully run before it starts complaining about available resources. (Keep in mind that I am the only user.)

I am running Nextcloud on strictly Home network not using an RPi. But may still be able to provide some thoughts/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that R Pi is specifically offered as an option when downloading Yunohost for installation, the answer is clearly "yes."